# prime numbers algorithm efficiency

Tags: primes, pseudocode

I have a question about prime numbers algorithm.

why in the following pseudo code i increases by 6 and not by 2 every iteration?

```
function is_prime(n)
if n ≤ 1
    return false
else if n ≤ 3
    return true
else if n mod 2 = 0 or n mod 3 = 0
    return false
let i ← 5
while i * i ≤ n
    if n mod i = 0 or n mod (i + 2) = 0
        return false
    i ← i + 6
return true
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it increased by 2 it would be testing almost everything twice, that wouldn't make any sense. So I assume you mean: how can it get away with not testing every odd number?

This is because every prime p greater than 3 is of the form 6n±1. Proof:
Consider the remainder r = p mod 6. Obviously r must be odd. Notice also that r cannot be 3, because then p would be divisible by 3, making it not a prime. This leaves only the possibilities 1 and 5, which correspond p being of the form 6n+1 or the form 6n-1 respectively.

The effect is that it avoid testing multiples of 3. Dividing by a multiple of 3 is redundant, because we already know that `n` is not a multiple of 3, so it cannot be the multiple of a multiple of 3 either.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment in the loop body is `i <- i + 6`, not `i <- i + 2`. In the `if` statement the expression `i + 2` just becomes a new value. There is no assignment operator in that expression.

Comment: That is the question OP asked. Why is it `i + 6`? I dont see an answer for that in your post.

Comment: Ah, I was answering the question too literally.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is based on the fact that prime numbers can be predicted using the formula `6k ± 1` and this does not apply on `2 and 3`.

For instance

`(6 * 1) - 1 = 5`

`(6 * 2) - 1 = 11`

`(6 * 3) - 1 = 17`

The list goes on and on.